# Unable to fix generator memory leak despite knowing where it's coming from

Tags: python, pandas, memory-leaks, zip

Apart from the zip files, which can be downloaded here,

https://data.binance.vision/?prefix=data/futures/um/daily/aggTrades/BTCUSDT/

here is a minimum reproducible example. First, download 3 or more zip files and get the filepaths of each zipfile. Then at the bottom of the script below, replace my filepaths in `file_list` with your filepaths:

```
from zipfile import ZipFile
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import psutil
import re

def print_memory_usage(msg):
    # Get memory usage information
    memory_info = psutil.virtual_memory()
    
    # Print memory usage details
    print(msg)
    print(f"Used: {memory_info.used / (1024 ** 3):.2f} GB")

def batch_generator(files: list):

    def _create_batch(file):
        return _read_file(file)

    for batch in files:
        df = _create_batch(batch)
        yield df

def _read_file(file):
    with ZipFile(file) as zipfile:
        csv_filename = re.split(r'/', file)[-1][:-4] + ".csv"
        with zipfile.open(csv_filename) as f:
            try:
                return read_aggtrades(f)
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
                raise Exception(f"Error occurred reading file: {csv_filename}")

def read_aggtrades(file) -> pd.DataFrame:

    # EX: 578304464,17085,0.01449000,684164672,684164672,14,True,True
    columns = ['a', 'price', 'q', 'first_trade_id', 'last_trade_id', 't', 'was_the_buyer_maker']
    usecols = ['a', 'price', 'q', 't']
    dtype = {'a': np.int64, 'price': str, 'q': str, 't': np.int64}

    def peek_line(f):
        pos = f.tell()
        line = f.readline()
        f.seek(pos)

        # Convert bytes to str (line can be bytes or str)
        if type(line) == bytes:
            return line.decode()

        return line

    def _read_csv(f1):
        # 99.9% files don't have headers, some do. Discard it if we encounter it by reading header line.
        first_line = peek_line(f1)
        if first_line.startswith('agg_trade_id'):
            f1.readline()
        return pd.read_csv(f1,
                         sep=',',
                         header=None,
                         names=columns,
                         usecols=usecols,
                         dtype=dtype)
    print_memory_usage("Before _read_csv")
    df = _read_csv(file)
    print_memory_usage("After _read_csv")

    return df

file_list = [
    "/home/owner/Desktop/BTCUSDT/BTCUSDT-aggTrades-2019-12-31.zip", \
    "/home/owner/Desktop/BTCUSDT/BTCUSDT-aggTrades-2020-01-01.zip", \
    "/home/owner/Desktop/BTCUSDT/BTCUSDT-aggTrades-2020-01-02.zip", \
    "/home/owner/Desktop/BTCUSDT/BTCUSDT-aggTrades-2020-01-03.zip"]
generator = batch_generator(file_list)

i = 0
for batch in generator:
    i += 1
    print(i)
```

As you will see when running it, the output shows a consistent increase in used memory:

```
Before _read_csv
Used: 10.31 GB
After _read_csv
Used: 10.31 GB
1
Before _read_csv
Used: 10.31 GB
After _read_csv
Used: 10.32 GB
2
Before _read_csv
Used: 10.32 GB
After _read_csv
Used: 10.33 GB
3
Before _read_csv
Used: 10.33 GB
After _read_csv
Used: 10.35 GB
4
```

I have no idea what to do. I tried adding `gc.collect()` and `del(batch)` after the print statement, and that doesn't help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using a different strategy for gathering the data seems to help.

No indication of a memory leak here.

```
import zipfile
from pathlib import Path
import psutil
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

maxmem = float("-inf")
minmem = float("inf")

def print_memory_usage(msg):
    global maxmem, minmem
    mem = psutil.virtual_memory().used / (1024 ** 3)
    maxmem = max(mem, maxmem)
    minmem = min(mem, minmem)
    print(f"{msg}: {mem:.2f} GB")


def read_aggtrades(file) -> pd.DataFrame:
    columns = [
        "agg_trade_id",
        "price",
        "quantity",
        "first_trade_id",
        "last_trade_id",
        "transact_time",
        "is_buyer_maker",
    ]
    usecols = ["agg_trade_id", "price", "quantity", "transact_time"]
    dtype = {
        "agg_trade_id": np.int64,
        "price": np.float64,
        "quantity": np.float64,
        "transact_time": np.int64,
    }

    def _read_csv(f1):
        c1, *_ = f1.readline().split(",")
        try:
            int(c1)
            f1.seek(0)
        except ValueError:
            pass
        return pd.read_csv(
            f1, sep=",", header=None, names=columns, usecols=usecols, dtype=dtype
        )

    print_memory_usage("Before _read_csv")
    df = _read_csv(file)
    print_memory_usage("After _read_csv")

    return df


def read_file(filename):
    with zipfile.ZipFile(filename) as z:
        zf, *_ = z.filelist
        z.extract(zf, DOWNLOADS)
        with open(DOWNLOADS / zf.filename) as data:
            return read_aggtrades(data)


def batch_generator(files):
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(8) as exe:
        yield from exe.map(read_file, files)


DOWNLOADS = Path("/Users/SIGHUP/Downloads")

dfs = []

for i, df in enumerate(batch_generator(DOWNLOADS.glob("BTCUSDT*zip"))):
    print(i)
    dfs.append(df)
    print(df.head())

print(f"{maxmem=:.2f}GB {minmem=:.2f}GB")
```

**Platform:**

```
macOS 14.4
Python 3.12.2
```

Comment: You don't see it because you didn't run enough files. You really start to see it around 100 files. I ran your code on hundreds of files and the memory leak is still there. In any case, I need to preserve the generator because I am working with hundreds of GB of data and that won't fit into memory.

Comment: In the OP you said "download 3 or more zip files" so that's exactly what I did and now you tell me I'm doing it wrong. FYI I've downloaded 67 ZIP archives and I run my code against them and see a maximum of 3.72GB and a minimum of 3.06GB. After processing the last file, those values are 3.13GB and 3.06GB respectively so there's no leak

Comment: I apologize, you're correct. It turns out what was causing the memory leak was not in this file. It was due to a use of tee to create two generators, and apparently generators created through tee have shared memory, which means the batches from one don't go out of scope until both are exhausted.